# UITextView UIResponderStandardEditActions Text Formatting Toggle State

Tags: ios, ios6, uitextview, toggle, uiresponder

How do I determine the current state of the [UIResponderStandardEditActions](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponderstandardeditactions) for text formatting? For example, if I do the following:

```
[textView toggleBoldface:nil];
```

How do I query the textView to find out if the state of bold is now on or off? This is for just a cursor with no selection (i.e. range length is 0). As such, enumerateAttribute doesn't seem to work.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the typingAttributes property (available in iOS 6) will log the attributes that will be applied to new text typed by the user, even with a selection length of 0. Thus revealing what the state of formatting options such as bold will be.

```
NSLog(@"textViewFormatting options: %@", [[self noteTextView] typingAttributes]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not finding anything useful in the docs, but I suppose it would be simple enough to just subclass UITextView, add a property on it like `BOOL boldText` and then wherever you call `[textView toggleBoldFace:nil];` just toggle that property as well. And then when you need to check the state of the textView, just check the `boldText` property instead.

Comment: Hi Gerald. I appreciate the suggestion, but I don't think it will work for a couple reasons. The main being that while bold is a BOOL, the state you expect to see can change without a toggle event (i.e. move the cursor). For example I may have 3 bold words. Putting the cursor between letters of any of those word should return a bold state. If I put the cursor between letters in a 4th word that is not bold, it should not return a bold state. So here, there is not a toggle event to change state. Just placing the cursor somewhere different should return a different result. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I did not realize that you would be changing the state via anything but toggle. I'll come back to this if I think of something useful.